# Simple Multi-threading help? C++, WaitForSingleObject and Synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, synchronization

So, I'm trying to make a simple multi-threaded program that validates the Collatz Conjecture for a large set of numbers and returns the total amount of validated numbers. Each thread (total 4) does an interval of numbers and updates the "validated" variable when a number reaches 1. I'm also timing the entire process (to compare vs a single threaded computation)

The problem I'm having is that there is never any consistency when I print out the "validated" int at the end of the program, so I am guessing that either the threads are writing over each other, or the main thread is completing before the others, thus printing an incomplete number. I'm also assuming that the clock() calculations will be off too, if the main thread is completing before the others. So, how do I STOP the main thread from continuing until the other threads are completed (thus making it wait for a updated validated count and complete an accurate time measurement)? This is what I thought WaitForSingleObject did, but I'm guessing it just stops the main thread from EXITING, still allowing it to compute its other functions.

This is my first go at any multi-threading, and I don't think I quite understand the workings of synchronization and the WaitForSingleObject command. Here is what I have so far in my main function:

***EDIT: Here is my updated Main function and Collatz function. I modified it so that each thread is accessing a separate variable to avoid the synchronization issue, but the problem still persists. There is no consistent value when I print out "validated" ****

***EDIT AGAIN: Alright, so I removed the "thread" int per Mladen Janković, and just used a simple counter to distribute the different intervals to the created threads. There is now a consistent, correct value for "validated". HOWEVER, I still cannot get the program to actually finish when there are 1,000,000 numbers. Testing it for 100,000 or even 10,000 works flawlessly, but when I up it to 1,000,000 numbers, the program runs indefinitely (hours) without actually returning a values. I'm guessing that it is getting stuck at a particular value (eg 750831 as Martin James pointed out). I tried substituting int for  long int, but it seems that it still suffers from overflow. Any suggestions? And thanks for the immense help.***

***LAST EDIT: Alright, so I just used long long instead of int and now the program works flawlessly. Thanks for the help everyone!***

```
void main() 
{
    clock_t start;
    clock_t finish;
    unsigned int thread = 0;

    start = clock();

    HANDLE h1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, collatz_thread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    HANDLE h2 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, collatz_thread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    HANDLE h3 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, collatz_thread, NULL, 0, NULL);

    for (int i = 750001 ; i <= 1000000 ; i++) { collatz(i, 4); }

    WaitForSingleObject( h1, INFINITE );
    WaitForSingleObject( h2, INFINITE );
    WaitForSingleObject( h3, INFINITE );

    finish = clock() - start;
    double time = finish / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    validated = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
    cout << validated << " numbers validated." << endl;
    cout << endl << time << " seconds." << endl;
}

unsigned _stdcall collatz_thread (void* n)
{   
    selection++; // selects a different interval each time collatz_thread is called

    switch (selection) {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 250000; i++)      { collatz(i, 1); }
        break;
    case 2:
        for (int i = 250001 ; i <= 500000; i++)  { collatz(i, 2); }
        break;
    case 3:
        for (int i = 500001 ; i <= 750000; i++)  { collatz(i, 3); }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

int collatz (int n, int thread)
{
    int original = n;

    while (n != 1) {
    if (n%2 == 0)
        n = (n/2);
    else
        n = (3*n + 1);
    }

    if (n == 1) {
    switch (thread) {
        case 1:
            v1++;
            break;
        case 2:
            v2++;
            break;
        case 3:
            v3++;
            break;
        case 4:
            v4++;
            break;
    }
    return n;
}
```

}

Comment: See my updated answer, and provide code for collatz_thread function.

Comment: Alright, there you go. I also updated the post with more information on my current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize access to `validated` if it is shared variable. The easies way is to use `InterlockedIncrement` function instead of standard `++` operator when you want to increment it. Another approach is to use some kind of synchronization object like spinlock or mutex when you access the shared variable, but that is overkill if you just need to synchronize increment operation.

If you want more details, please provide code of `collatz` function.

As 'usr' suggested, for the better performance you can use separate variable fore each thread and then sum them in the main thread. In this scenario, you should pad those variables in such a way so they don't share same cache-line to avoid [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

You haven't provided `collatz_thread` function, which could be another cause of inconsistent results. The reason is you pass *pointer* to variable (`&thread`) that stores thread # which changes between the calls that create new threads, so depending on the state of the OS's scheduler the new threads might not get a chance to start while `thread` variable is already changed to have another value, so then you'll have more then one thread doing the same set of data, while other sets might be skipped. Since the behavior depends on current state of thread scheduler it's pretty much unpredictable.

The solution is cast `thread` variable to `void*` instead of passing its address and then in `collatz_thread` function cast it back to `int`:

`HANDLE h1 = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, collatz_thread, (void*)thread, 0, NULL);`

And as Martin suggested, you possibly have integer overflow, but it shouldn't cause inconsistent results, just wrong results, but consistent nevertheless.

Comment: True. If you use InterlockedIncrement though you won't get high troughput. Better to use one variable per thread.

Comment: @usr: that's even better solution for this simple case.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion. Should I time (using clock() funtions) each thread individually too, or is how I have it sufficient to get an accurate time for the entire process?

Comment: There's no point in timing each thread on its own, since you want get time of complete process.

Comment: Alright, I updated the post with a modified collatz function using separate variables, but the same problem persists. How would I go about "padding" the variables? Also, thanks for the link. I've never heard of "false sharing."

Comment: Is it me or is that collatz algorithm unstable?  If I call it with 750831 then it runs into integer overflow.

Comment: Do we need a 64-bit box/compiler?

Comment: I tried this with Visual C++ on my 64-bit box. I got a consistent validated of 7993360.  Anyone tried this or know the expected value?  With 4 threads on my i7 I get 345ms. With 8 I get 333ms, which is odd because there are only the 4 'x to x+250000',  tasks on the pool.  One thread takes 1014ms :(

Comment: @ Martin James
Well, unless I just disproved the Collatz Conjecture (doubtful), the return value for the full program should be 1,000,000, which is the amount of numbers tested. 

My original problem is now solved - the error was in the assignment of values the thread int. By the time the new threads were created, thread was already reassigned, making only the last two intervals compute.

Still, I'm curious as to how your getting such low runtimes. My i5 is fine up until a max of 100,000 (runtimes of low 100 ms), but as soon as I try 1,000,000, the program runs indefinitely (hours)!

Comment: ... Which suggests there is still an error somewhere in my implementation. How did you get it running @MartinJames?

Comment: ..and ther it is. I left in my integer-overflow trap from running on 32-bit code. This caused the iteration to return early :(  Now I have taken the trap out, thr 64-bit version is taking a long time, as expected.   That also explains the err.. 'disproof of the Collatz Conjecture' <g>

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a look at this :

[Semaphore and threads explenation from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811896)

It's probably the best documentation you'll find online.

Now, regarding you code, I assume it isn't working quite well and this is the reason why :
WaitForSingleObject - Basicly means that you try to do a -1 on the h1 semaphore (or h2 or h3) and if you cannot do that -1 (i.e the semaphore is at 0) then wait for an infinite time.
WaitForSimgleObject should actually be called in your thread routine and not in you main.

Also, in you thread object, once you're done working on the shared variable, you need to Release the semaphore so that other thread can get the lock on that particular Semaphore.

Try to look at the example on the link I gave you and i'm sure you'll make it work quicly.

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at this and am getting some results that are good, too good :((  Something is wrong somewhere, but I don't see it.  I am not getting runtimes in the order of hours, even for n from 1 to 10,000,000, (ten million):

```
8 tests,
8 tasks,
counting to 1000000,
using 14 threads:
Validated: 1000000 in 670ms
Validated: 1000000 in 671ms
Validated: 1000000 in 624ms
Validated: 1000000 in 656ms
Validated: 1000000 in 655ms
Validated: 1000000 in 655ms
Validated: 1000000 in 640ms
Validated: 1000000 in 686ms
Average time: 657ms
Total validated: 8000000

8 tests,
8 tasks,
counting to 10000000,
using 14 threads:
Validated: 10000000 in 8081ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7441ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7784ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7598ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7956ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7534ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7816ms
Validated: 10000000 in 7769ms
Average time: 7747ms
Total validated: 80000000
```

Note that, although it says 14 threads, that is for the whole pool.  One thread is always used up waiting for other tasks to complete, so only 13 threads were actually available to run the validation.  For some reason, that was optimum.

OK, my i7 is flat-out on all 4/8 cores, but I can't see runtimes of hours shrinking into seconds just because I have more cores and have split off the work to all of them :(

This is what I used. It's a bit different to the way you did it 'cos I had most of the tools/code lying around.  It's Visual C++, to start with.  There are two classes.  Each run is managed by a 'PoolTest' class that submits several 'TestTask' instances to a threadpool, one for each segment of the complete range of integers to be validated.  You will notice your code copied/pasted into the TestTask class.  I highlighted where the TestTask is assembled in the PoolTest code. The 'PoolTest' class then waits on an Event for all the 'TestTask' instances to complete - it can do this because the TestTask's call back to a PoolTest 'taskComplete' method on completion. This method accesses a  thread-safe counter that is counted up when TestTasks are submitted and counted down by the 'taskComplete' method.

This code I've re-used complicates things a bit because it can repeat the run multiple times to get an average time, so the complete set of TestTasks can be issued mutiple times.

When the last ever TestTask counts down to zero, it signals the Event and the PoolTest will then run again signaling completion of the whole test run to the GUI, (not bothered listing GUI stuff 'cos not relevant).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public class TestTask: Task{
public int validated;
public int fromVal, toVal;
public int ticks;

    long collatz(long n)
    {
        while (n != 1)
        {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                n = (n / 2);
            else
                n = (3 * n + 1);
        }
        return (n);
    }

    public override void run(){
        int index;
        int localTo = toVal;
        int localFrom = fromVal;
        int localVal = 0;
        for (index = localFrom; index < localTo; index++)
        {  // if not disproved, inc the stack 'validated'
            if (1 == collatz(index + 1)) localVal++;
        }
        validated = localVal; // put stack result into instance field,
    }
    public TestTask(int paramx, EventHandler OnDone)
        : base(paramx, OnDone){}
};


/* a task that submits testTask instances.
*/
public class PoolTest:Task{
    int FnumTasks;
    int FnumTests;
    int Fcount;
    int FtestCount;
    int taskCount;
    int startTicks;
    int endTicks;
    int totalTicks;
    EventHandler FonTaskComplete;
    AutoResetEvent  testCompleteEvent;
    public int average;
    public int testTicks;
    public int Vone;
    public int Vtot;
    public TestTask thisTestTask;

    public PoolTest(int testsNum, int tasks, int count, EventHandler taskDone,
        EventHandler testDone)
        : base(0, testDone)
    {
        FnumTests=testsNum;
        FtestCount=testsNum;
        FnumTasks=tasks;
        Fcount=count;
        Vtot = 0;
        Vone = 0;
        totalTicks = 0;
        FonTaskComplete=taskDone; // call after each test to report ticks
        testCompleteEvent= new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }
    void submitAtest(){  // queue up numTasks testTask instances
        taskCount=FnumTasks;
        startTicks = System.Environment.TickCount;

//*********************THIS IS WHERE THE RANGES AND TASKS ARE ASSEMBLED

        int startNum = 0;   // here, start at 0 and build up the ranges
        int countIncrement=Fcount/FnumTasks;  // calc. range size
        int endNum=startNum+countIncrement;   // and so init. start/end  
        TestTask newTask;
        for (int i = 1; i < FnumTasks; i++) // one less than requested
        {
            newTask=new TestTask(0, taskComplete);
            newTask.fromVal=startNum;   // load in the start/end for the loop
            newTask.toVal = endNum;
            myPool.submit(newTask);     // off it goes, see you later
            startNum = endNum;          // now move range up for  
            endNum += countIncrement;     // next TestTask
        }
        // treat last range separately to cover div rounding when
        // calculating 'countIncrement'
        newTask = new TestTask(0, taskComplete); // do last one
        newTask.fromVal = startNum;
        newTask.toVal = Fcount;
        myPool.submit(newTask);   // send off the last one
    }

//*****************************************************************

    public override void run(){
        submitAtest(); //start off the first run of testTasks
        testCompleteEvent.WaitOne();
    }
    void taskComplete(object sender, EventArgs e){  // called when a testTask
        bool finishedTasks;                         // instance is complete
         lock (this)
        {
            thisTestTask = (TestTask)sender;
            taskCount--;                            // another one down
            Vone += thisTestTask.validated;         // Vone - total for one run
            Vtot += thisTestTask.validated;         // total for all runs
            finishedTasks = (taskCount == 0);       // this run all done yet?
            if (finishedTasks)
            {
                endTicks = System.Environment.TickCount; // yes, so calc. elapsed time
                testTicks=endTicks-startTicks;
                thisTestTask.ticks = testTicks;
                totalTicks=totalTicks+testTicks;
                if (0!=--FtestCount) {                   // done all the test runs?
                    thisTestTask.validated = Vone;       // use this field to return run total
                    FonTaskComplete(thisTestTask, null); // and signal result of test
                    Vone = 0;
                    submitAtest();                      // no, so send off another load
                }
                else{
                        average=totalTicks/FnumTests;     // done all test runs!
                        testCompleteEvent.Set();          // signal all runs completed
                    };
            }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: I think my problem was indeed the integer overflow you mentioned earlier. I isolated the case of 750831 and tested it individually, and the results indicated that it did indeed suffer from integer overflow, making the loop run far longer (hours) than it should have (yet somehow it still made its way to 1?). After I made the int n into long long, the program ran and validated all 1,000,000 numbers in 1314ms using 4 threads on my Core i5. For a single thread, the program took 3359ms. So, your results are probably correct and mine were just out of whack.